# Unable to create role with cassandra 4

Tags: cassandra, roles, cql

I'm trying to create roles in Cassandra while logged in as the default cassandra user and this error pops up :

```
[root@node1 ~]# cqlsh -u admin -p admin@123
Connected to Test Cluster at 127.0.0.1:9042
[cqlsh 6.0.0 | Cassandra 4.0.1 | CQL spec 3.4.5 | Native protocol v5]
Use HELP for help.
admin@cqlsh> CREATE ROLE cassweb WITH PASSWORD = 'Cassweb@1234' AND SUPERUSER = true AND LOGIN = true;
Unauthorized: Error from server: code=2100 [Unauthorized] message="Only superusers can create a role with superuser status"
```

I should also note that I've changed `authenticator: AllowAllAuthenticator` to `authenticator: PasswordAuthenticator` and `authorizer: AllowAllAuthorizer` to `authorizer: CassandraAuthorizer` in the cassandra.yaml file and have restarted the Cassandra service after making those changes but the error still pops up.

Comment: Just an observation, but there's nothing about Cassandra that requires it or cqlsh to be run as the "root" user.  In fact, creating a special "cassandra" user should be part of your deploy process.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen that error message before, and it can be caused by more than what it's reporting.

> I should also note that I've changed...in the cassandra.yaml file

Just to be thorough, run this query on the `settings` virtual table, and make sure that you get similar results:

```
> SELECT * FROM system_views.settings
  WHERE name IN ('authenticator','authorizer');

 name          | value
---------------+-----------------------
 authenticator | PasswordAuthenticator
    authorizer |   CassandraAuthorizer
```

> logged in as the default cassandra user

So when I look at your output above, it looks like your user name is "admin," and that is *not* the default user.

Try running this query on the `system_auth` table:

```
> SELECT role,is_superuser FROM system_auth.roles;
```

If your user is not a superuser, then it will not able able to create another superuser.

You might have to try creating the new user as the cassandra/cassandra user. <shrug/>